# How to find which user delete firestore collection from firestore console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We gave 10 users to access our firebase console. Someone delete our main `collection` in firestore.

Is there a way to find out which user removes it from these 10 users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There currently is no way to find out which collaborator on the project or which Authentication user deleted the collection from Firestore. The feature has been considered though, so I recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

you should never give access for users to your firebase console only developers and app owners should be allowed to access it. but if you want to track users activity you  can use Firebase analytics event logging.Events are triggered when users take actions in your app for more information[Firebase analytics event logging](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjI79Djj6byAhVa5eAKHfbJBe8QFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fanalytics%2Fevents&usg=AOvVaw3P509UceK4B99npA5dXkHo)

Comment: Now, I delete `users` collection from the firebase console web app. Is it possible to track it?

Comment: no its not Firebase web console is designed for developers and owner of the app its like accessing the database directly users should access your database through your web app in that way  you can  track users action by using Firebase analytics